# How to make a class inheriting of serializable class not serializable ever?

Tags: java, inheritance, serializable

Let's consider the following code:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private long secretInfo = ...

}
```

`JPanel` is `Serializable`. However, `MyPanel` should not be `Serializable` ever, because it contains sensitive information.

How to cleanly cancel/prevent the inherited `Serializable` aspect from `JPanel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the following approaches:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private long secretInfo = ...

    // refuse to be serialized!
    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        throw new IllegalStateException("MyPanel cannot be serialized");
    }
}
```

or

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    // flag the serialization mechanism to ignore
    // sensitive information
    private transient long secretInfo = ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You mark the fields you don't want to serialize as [`transient`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/transient):

```
private transient long secretInfo = ...
```

You can still serialize `MyPanel`, but its sensitive information won't be serialized.

Also, you could consider an alternative design where the sensitive information is stored in a separate non-serializable class.

Comment: True, I could, but then a hacker could unserializable MyPanel in a potentially corrupted state, which is not secure.

Answer (score 2):

Don't extend JPanel. Problem solved. Try something like this instead:

```
class MyPanel {
    void doSomething();
    String getSomeValue();
    JPanel getDisplayComponent();
}
```

MyPanel logically represents a panel in your app, but there's no particular requirement for it to extend JPanel. Composition is often a more powerful relationship.